# Android 5: Bluetooth pairing dialog has no passkey form

Tags: bluetooth, 5.0-lollipop

I use several Bluetooth devices with my phone. Today I tried to pair a new one and was shown this dialog:

```
Bluetooth pairing request

Device
NWP-F110

Type the pairing code then press Return or Enter

Cancel                                      Pair
```

No keyboard pops up. If I tap around inside the dialog, nothing happens. If I hit `Cancel` the pairing fails. If I hit `Pair` the device is registered in my Bluetooth system settings, but the app that works with it is unable to access it. According to the manufacturer, a passcode is necessary and apparently Android thinks so too, but I'm unable to enter it.

If I continue nonetheless and try to setup the device, the app searches endlessly. I'm never asked for the pairing code again until I manually forget the device in the system settings, yet no device is able to work with it.

Googling only shows me how to add the device as a trusted device, I'm unable to find any similar problems for Android 5 (although it might be because the OS is so new). Any tips?

I've confirmed that this is specific to my Nexus 5 running Android 5 - my Samsung S3 pairs with the device almost instantly and without trouble.

Comment: Prior to "obsoleting the hardware keys" (or on devices still having them), long-pressing the "menu" button often brings it up in such cases. I don't have a Nexus to check, but maybe there's something similar you could try? Some "overflow menu button" visible, perhaps?

Comment: Sadly, no - it's shown in a full-screen app, where the status bar and menu are offscreen. Holding the dialog and swiping down from the top bring them back, but there's no way of calling up a keyboard or menu from there.

Comment: That's really sad – and I'm out of ideas then. Wish you luck, hopefully some other Nexus-5 user has a solution for you.

Comment: Same problem over here: Nexus 5, Jabra Rox Wireless headphones